# How to invoke multiple instances using timer events in C#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, event-handling, timertask

**Problem Statement**

I have a module code written in C# which waits for a topic called 'start' and as soon as it's received, then I need to send certain data periodically based om time interval. I need to accommodate my logic in such a way that 'start' topic can be called multiple times with different metadata value and all those has to run it's own instance with the same logic.

**Issue I am Facing**

Now the code always runs only one instance of 'SendPeriodicTelemetry' even though 'start' topic is invoked multiple times.

**Code Snippet Sample**

The below three classes are given with the order the call goes

```
public static async void MessageReceiveAsync(object sender, MqttApplicationMessageReceivedEventArgs e)
        {            
            Console.WriteLine($"Message received on topic: '{e.ApplicationMessage.Topic}'. Payload: {msg}");           
            try
            {
                if (e.ApplicationMessage.Topic.Contains("methods"))
                {                   
                    await PublisherClass.PublishToMethod(topicElement, msg);
                }
            }
        }


public static class PublisherClass
    {
         public static bool StartInvoked { get; set; }
         public static int StartCmdCount { get; set; } = 0;
          public static async Task PublishToMethod(string methodName, string message)
        {
            try
            {
                string topic;                
                var sendPeriodicTelemetries = new SendPeriodicTelemetry[10];
                switch (methodName)
                {         
                    case "stop":                        
                        for (int i = 0; i < StartCmdCount; i++)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine($"start command index to stop: {i}");
                            sendPeriodicTelemetries[StartCmdCount].aTimer.Stop();
                            sendPeriodicTelemetries[StartCmdCount].aTimer.Dispose();
                        }
                        StartInvoked = false;
                        StartCmdCount = 0;
                        await CommonMethods.AckMethod(CommonMethods.listMessage, CommonMethods.requestId, MethodNames.sendTimeSeries);
                        break;

                    case "start":                      
                        sendPeriodicTelemetries[StartCmdCount] = new SendPeriodicTelemetry();                        
                        sendPeriodicTelemetries[StartCmdCount].TsAlarmAndEventTopicAndPayload(rawPayload, objId);                       
                        sendPeriodicTelemetries[StartCmdCount].aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(timeIntervel);             
                        sendPeriodicTelemetries[StartCmdCount].SetTimer(timeIntervel, sendPeriodicTelemetries[StartCmdCount].aTimer);
                        StartCmdCount++;              
                        break;                   
                }
            }

            catch(Exception exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Exception occurred: {exception.ToString()}");
            }
        }        
    }
    
    public class SendPeriodicTelemetry
    {
       
        public void TsAlarmAndEventTopicAndPayload(JObject rawPayload, string objId)
        {
            
        }

        public void SetTimer(int timeInterval, Timer timer)
        {
            if (!PublisherClass.StartInvoked)
            {               
                PublisherClass.StartInvoked = true;
                timer.Elapsed += SendPeriodic;
                timer.AutoReset = true;
                timer.Enabled = true;
            }
        }

        public async void SendPeriodic(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {           
            Console.WriteLine("Starting to send periodic Telemetry at {0:HH:mm:ss.fff}", e.SignalTime);
            await SendPeriodicTimeSeries(PublisherClass.TimeSeriesTopic, PublisherClass.TelemetrySingle, PublisherClass.Configuration);
            await SendPeriodicAlarm(PublisherClass.AlarmTopic, PublisherClass.AlarmSingle);
            await SendPeriodicEvent(PublisherClass.EventTopic, PublisherClass.EventSingle);
        }

        public async Task SendPeriodicTimeSeries(string topic, TelemetrySingle payload, JObject configuration)
        {
           
        }

        public async Task SendPeriodicAlarm(string topic, AlarmSingle payload)
        {
           
        }

        public async Task SendPeriodicEvent(string topic, EventSingle payload)
        {
           
        }
    }
```

**Scenario Flow**

1. Consider from 'MessageReceiveAsync' I received a topic that contains a method(not C# method) called 'start' with some metadata for the first time then the 'PublishToMethod' is invoked with that method name ('start')
2. Then based on the metadata received inside 'start' case I initiate the timer to particular interval based on the metadata received along-with 'start' command.
3. Then all three below data will be sent on the set time intervals

   ```
            await SendPeriodicTimeSeries(PublisherClass.TimeSeriesTopic, 
                            PublisherClass.TelemetrySingle, PublisherClass.Configuration);
            await SendPeriodicAlarm(PublisherClass.AlarmTopic, PublisherClass.AlarmSingle);
            await SendPeriodicEvent(PublisherClass.EventTopic, PublisherClass.EventSingle);
   ```
4. Consider from 'MessageReceiveAsync' I received another topic that contains a method(not C# method) called 'start' again for the second time with a different metadata. It can hit any number of times.
5. Then again the specific timeinterval should be set for the timer and timer event has to go periodically for different kind of metadata
6. The previous periodic data should also go ahead as usual
7. Also whenever a 'stop' method is invoked the periodic timer events for all instances should stop.

**Actual Result**

As soon as I receive the 'start' for the second time the first invoked metadata values all switched to the second time invoked values and always the periodic data goes for the latest invoked value. Only one instance is running always. I want to send periodic data for as many instances as the number of times 'start' is invoked.

**Expected Result**

Multiple instances of timer event should get invoked and the below methods should keep sending the data according to the metadata received

```
        await SendPeriodicTimeSeries(PublisherClass.TimeSeriesTopic, 
        PublisherClass.TelemetrySingle, PublisherClass.Configuration);
        await SendPeriodicAlarm(PublisherClass.AlarmTopic, PublisherClass.AlarmSingle);
        await SendPeriodicEvent(PublisherClass.EventTopic, PublisherClass.EventSingle);
```

Comment: "Only one instance is running always."  You have `if (!PublisherClass.StartInvoked)` followed by `PublisherClass.StartInvoked = true;`...but I don't see anywhere except for the "stop" command where you reset this value, so only the first one will ever run.

Comment: Also, in your calls to the "SendPeriodicXXX()" methods, you are passing STATIC values as the parameters, so you'll only ever pass whatever was last stored in the those variables.  Seems like you should be passing INSTANCE members there instead, but it's hard to tell as there isn't enough code to make that determination.

Comment: Thanks that gives me hint to change calling using the 'SendPeriodicTelemetry' object instead of using 'PublisherClass' static class. This is the stripped down version of the same code I am using. If you require any further details please let me know. I will provide as much details I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem in Timer object initialization. It was still from a static class and hence changed that with the 'SendPeriodicTelemetry' instance level property. Then now I could able to invoke multiple instances with the specified time interval. And for stopping those time based events I need to dispose the Timer. That's it. Achieved my objective. And it's not required to initialize the
'SendPeriodicTelemetry' object as array to achieve that.

```
public static async void MessageReceiveAsync(object sender, MqttApplicationMessageReceivedEventArgs e)
    {            
        Console.WriteLine($"Message received on topic: '{e.ApplicationMessage.Topic}'. Payload: {msg}");           
        try
        {
            if (e.ApplicationMessage.Topic.Contains("methods"))
            {                   
                await PublisherClass.PublishToMethod(topicElement, msg);
            }
        }
    }


public static class PublisherClass
{   
     public static List<System.Timers.Timer> SendPeriodicTimerObjs { get; set; } = new List<System.Timers.Timer>();
     public static async Task PublishToMethod(string methodName, string message)
    {
        try
        {                
            switch (methodName)
            {       
                case "start":
                case "stop":                        
                    var sendPeriodicObj = new SendPeriodicTelemetry();
                    sendPeriodicObj.periodicTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
                    SendPeriodicTimerObjs.Add(sendPeriodicObj.periodicTimer);
                    if (methodName == "start")
                    {                                             
                        sendPeriodicObj.TsAlarmAndEventTopicAndPayload(rawPayload, objId);                           
                        sendPeriodicObj.periodicTimer.Interval = timeIntervel;                           
                        sendPeriodicObj.SetTimer(timeIntervel, sendPeriodicObj.periodicTimer);                
                    }
                    else
                    {                
                        sendPeriodicObj.periodicTimer.Stop();                            
                        foreach(var timer in SendPeriodicTimerObjs)
                        {
                            timer.Dispose();
                        }                           
                        SendPeriodicTimerObjs.Clear();                 
                    }
                    break;                
            }
        }

        catch(Exception exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Exception occurred: {exception.ToString()}");
        }
    }        
}

public class SendPeriodicTelemetry
{
    public System.Timers.Timer periodicTimer;
    
    public void TsAlarmAndEventTopicAndPayload(JObject rawPayload, string objId)
    {
        
    }

    public void SetTimer(int timeInterval, Timer timer)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Inside SetTimer method");
        StartInvoked = true;
        timer.Elapsed += SendPeriodic;
        timer.AutoReset = true;
        timer.Enabled = true;           
    }  

    public async void SendPeriodic(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {           
        Console.WriteLine("Starting to send periodic Telemetry at {0:HH:mm:ss.fff}", e.SignalTime);
        await SendPeriodicTimeSeries(PublisherClass.TimeSeriesTopic, PublisherClass.TelemetrySingle, PublisherClass.Configuration);
        await SendPeriodicAlarm(PublisherClass.AlarmTopic, PublisherClass.AlarmSingle);
        await SendPeriodicEvent(PublisherClass.EventTopic, PublisherClass.EventSingle);
    }

    public async Task SendPeriodicTimeSeries(string topic, TelemetrySingle payload, JObject configuration)
    {
       
    }

    public async Task SendPeriodicAlarm(string topic, AlarmSingle payload)
    {
       
    }

    public async Task SendPeriodicEvent(string topic, EventSingle payload)
    {
       
    }
}
```